# How to avoid subscribe soup?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming, observable

I have a pattern that comes a lot and I'm not sur what is the best way to solve it.

I have a subscription to an observable (here to the router) that gives me values. I need one of these values to build another request to get another observable. But I have then an observable in a subscription.

I know this is not a good pattern but I don't know how else to do this.

And if I use this 2nd observable to fetch another value and get another observable in observable of observable.

**How to solve this and avoid soup?**

Here is my code:

**deal.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy} from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {DealsService} from "../deals.service";

@Component({
  templateUrl: './+deal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./+deal.component.scss']
})
export class DealRouterComponent implements OnInit {

  deal$: Observable<any>;
  public dealId:string;
  private sub:any;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private dealsService: DealsService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params
      .subscribe(params => {
        this.dealId = params['id'];
        this.deal$ = this.dealsService.getDeal(this.dealId);
      })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.sub.unsubscribe();
  }

}
```

**deal.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable, Inject} from "@angular/core";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {AngularFireDatabase} from "angularfire2";

@Injectable()
export class DealsService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) {}

  getDeal(id) {
    return this.db.object('deals/' + id);
  }

 }
```

**deal.component.html**

```
{{deal | async | json}}
```

Comment: This pattern is similar to nested 'promise hell'. The solution is to chain observables with mergeMap (flatMap) operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observable are chainable through [operators](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html). That's one of the strength of observable and I found [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754) to be one of the best to explain how to work with ReactiveX.

You should not change observable like you do for `deal$`. Assuming your service is only returning one deal from an id, you're building an `Observable` per deal while I assume what you want is an `Observable` that will emit deals over time. Also you'll have to constantly re-subscribe to the new `deal$`. Previous `Subscription` will continue to listen to the old `deal$` and never get new values.

```
export class DealRouterComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit() {
    this.deal$ = this.route.params.flatMap(params => 
      this.dealsService.getDeal(this.dealId = params['id'])
    );  
  }
}
```

That way every time route's params get updated `deal$` will emit a new deal from your service.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer really helped me understand this.